# Add information about backticks to comment help

Tags: feature-request, comments, help

I suggest to add information about backticks to the comment help.

They can be used to mark code in comments too (in case some one does not know ;o)).

**Update:**

Uh, I should go to bed.... it's already there, never mind guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's already there:

> Comments use mini-Markdown formatting:
>   [link](http://example.com) _italic_
>   **bold** **`code`**.

Comment: Oops, I was too quick in reading.... thanks. Maybe it should be more obvious then ;) (just trying to rescue myself ;))

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work:

`  g_Setup.RibbonMinimized                      :=ribMain.Minimized;
  g_Setup.Rpt_NewPageAfterEachSessionChildItem :=actRpt_NewPageAfterEachSessionChildItem.Checked;`

Comment: @X-Ray, it's working fine for me:  `g_Setup.RibbonMinimized :=ribMain.Minimized; g_Setup.Rpt_NewPageAfterEachSessionChildItem :=actRpt_NewPageAfterEachSessionChildItem.Checked;`  That much code you're probably better off putting in an edit, though.

Comment: `g_Setup.RibbonMinimized :=ribMain.Minimized; g_Setup.Rpt_NewPageAfterEachSessionChildItem :=actRpt_NewPageAfterEachSessionChildItem.Checked;`

Comment: i see...no spaces shall occur right after the first backtick.  thanks!